# How to use addin interface in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Following is a code sample of Addin I copied from MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.addin.aspx) and did some modifications to. I create a Add-in project by VS2008 and paste the following code into it.

But it seems that it does not work properly.

1> DTE Add-in count before and after the  Update does not change

2> Guid of the added addin is all zeros

3> I get error: The parameter is incorrect, at code line: DTE.Solution.AddIns.Add

```
    Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection
    _applicationObject = CType(application, DTE2)
    _addInInstance = CType(addInInst, AddIn)
    Me.AddInExample(_applicationObject)
End Sub
Function BrowseFile() As String
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "*.dll file (*.dll)|*.dll|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1dialog
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'MsgBox(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Return OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
    Return ""
End Function
Sub AddInExample(ByVal DTE As DTE2)
    ' For this example to work correctly, there should be an add-in 
    ' available in the Visual Studio environment.
    ' Set object references.
    Dim addincoll As AddIns
    Dim addinobj As AddIn
    ' Register an add-in, check DTE Add-in count before and after the 
    ' Update.
    addincoll = DTE.AddIns
    MsgBox("AddIns collection parent name: " & addincoll.Parent.Name)
    MsgBox("Number of Add-ins: " & addincoll.Count)
    ' NOTE: Use regsvr32 for Visual C++, regasm for [Visual Basic 
    ' and Visual C#. Also, the pathname used below is an example only.
    'Shell("regasm F:\AddIns\RegExplore\Debug\regexplore.dll")
    'Shell("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm e:\AddinTest1.dll")
    Shell("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm " & BrowseFile())
    addincoll.Update()
    MsgBox("Number of Add-ins: " & addincoll.Count)
    addinobj = addincoll.Item(1)
    ' Connect the add-in if it is not already connected
    ' and list its SatelliteDLLPath and Guid.
    If addinobj.Connected = False Then
        addinobj.Connected = True
    End If
    MsgBox("Satellite DLL Path: " & addinobj.SatelliteDllPath)
    MsgBox("DLL GUID: " & addinobj.Guid)
    ' Activates a solution add-in so that it is available, then 
    'deactivates it.
    MsgBox(addinobj.ProgID)
    MsgBox(addinobj.Description)
    MsgBox(addinobj.Name)
    addinobj = DTE.Solution.AddIns.Add(addinobj.ProgID, addinobj.Description, addinobj.Name, False)
    DTE.Solution.AddIns.Item(1).Remove()
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?  This is not about building an add-in, it is about allowing your add-in to get some information about other add-ins.  Is that what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Hi Steve, I want to know that after I run following code, why there is no item associated the addin appears in the Addin Manager? Thanks. [code begin] Shell("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm " & BrowseFile())
[code end]

Answer (score 0):

I would start at the begining if I were you: [MSDN VS Addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Doing it this way allows you to debug (step-through) your code and will give you a good start.  The page you are on assumes you already know how to do this.

Comment: I just created the addin project following the article you refer, and then paste the example code into the project.

Comment: I found a article about creating Solution Addin, let me see if it can be helpful.

Comment: I found that the example code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.addin.aspx shows how 

to register a solution addin after I read article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165621(v=vs.90).aspx). Then I following that article to create a 

solution addin:

1> Create an addin project and accept all default settings.

2> Right click the addin project, select Properties, check Register for COM interop box.

3> Build the addin project.

But it's unlucky that when I run the example code to register the solution addin, I get same result as 

previously I get.

Thanks.